# Reverse Proxy with User Management

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy

I am looking for a reverse proxy with user management, if possible with a UI. Does anybody
know a software to handle multiple server connections and to create users with restricted access to only one specific client?

My second question: Is it possible to include the content of reverse proxy into an existing webpage hosted by an other webserver?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First part of your Question (I know this is late):

You may want to checkout **pritunl** or ory **oathkeeper**

https://zero.pritunl.com/

https://www.ory.sh/docs/oathkeeper/

Pritunl is a reverse proxy with UI usermanagement but you can't use it to protect paid services since the license disallows commercial use.
Oathkeeper is a bit more complex but 100% open source Apache 2.0.

You also may want to take a look at https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/ which is "Authentication Based on Subrequest Result".